# Vaadin button text appearing below button and is invisible

Tags: css, vaadin

I have an app where suddenly all of my buttons in Vaadin do not show their icon/text.  When I use the element inspector in Chrome I see that the class .v-button-wrap has been set in the  tag of my page (not in the .css theme file) and has its display set to block.  if I turn off display:block I can see my text again.  I cannot figure out however where this incorrect css style is being generated in my app.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Are you using any custom styles (i.e., rules in <your-theme>.scss) ?

Comment: The `display: block` for the v-button-wrap element is correct, but the fact that the selector is not wrapped with `.valo` looks like an issue. It also looks like that style is coming from somewhere else than your theme file (inspector shows `<style></style>` as the source vs. `styles.css?v=7.7.6`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had Vaadin Touchkit registered in my widgetset config file (.gwt.xml file).  Once I removed this everything works fine.  It appears Touchkit injects a  tag into your  element.